How to transpose subset of columns into rows and group by remainder of rows? Excel? SQL?
We are in the early stages of migrating some data from a legacy system to a new system that seems to have some quirks.
Currently we have some data that is as follows
Name      Date      Award
Roger  2024-06-01     A1
Roger  2024-06-01     A2
Roger  2024-07-01     A3
Alice  2024-06-01     A4
Alice  2024-07-01     A5
Aidan  2024-01-01     A6

I was trying to get the data into the following format
Name   2024-06-01  2024-06-01  2024-07-01  2024-01-01
Roger       A1         A2          A3          -
Alice       A4          -          A5          -
Aidan       -           -          -           A6

Few issues with the data is that the number of rows can be variable. Thus when pivoting the number of columns can also be variable. The other issue is if I was trying to pivot on "Date" there can be times when an individual may get more then one award on a day, so the "Date" column could also be duplicated a few times.
I tried to do a search and found a few different solutions one via SQL (our data is coming from Oracle) and the next option was Excel Power Query.
When I searched for a SQL solution I found Oracle has the pivot function but this would require aggregation. I was then able to find maybe I could use a MAX or MIN function (conditional aggregation?) - But unfortunately this would cause some data to be lost -> For example with "Roger" on 2024-06-01 only one award would be in the output.
Looking for an Excel option I was able to find an article that suggested using Excel Power Query to pivot the table data. This seemed to work fine until I hit this row:
Name      Date      Award
Roger  2024-06-01     A1
Roger  2024-06-01     A2

It threw an error alluding to how it can not aggregate the row to column since there were 2 values of 2024-06-01. Again if I used MAX/MIN it would fix the error but then I would lose either the A1 or A2 award data.
I know Pivot is fundamentally meant to aggregate/group values so I am having a tough time finding how to get the desired output. Not sure if SQL or Excel would be the best way to go about things or if this is totally nonsensical request I would appreciate any ideas or input

How can you have two columns with the same name? How would you refer to 2024-06-01 and 2024-06-01 as they're the exact same name...

@davidebacci You can display multiple columns with the same identifier fiddle. Using it in another query would raise errors because of the duplicate identifier but for display purposes it is possible.

Did none of these answers solve your issue ?

In Oracle, you can use PIVOT and LISTAGG:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
       PIVOT(
         LISTAGG(award, ',')
         FOR dt IN (
           DATE '2024-01-01' AS "2024-01-01",
           DATE '2024-06-01' AS "2024-06-01",
           DATE '2024-07-01' AS "2024-07-01"
         )
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, DT, Award) AS
SELECT 'Roger',  DATE '2024-06-01', 'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Roger',  DATE '2024-06-01', 'A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Roger',  DATE '2024-07-01', 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice',  DATE '2024-06-01', 'A4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice',  DATE '2024-07-01', 'A5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aidan',  DATE '2024-01-01', 'A6' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



NAME
2024-01-01
2024-06-01
2024-07-01




Aidan
A6
null
null


Alice
null
A4
A5


Roger
null
A1,A2
A3



Or, numbering the rows before pivoting:
SELECT *
FROM   (
          SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, dt ORDER BY award) AS rn
          FROM   table_name t
       )
       PIVOT(
         MAX(award)
         FOR (dt, rn) IN (
           (DATE '2024-01-01', 1) AS "2024-01-01_1",
           (DATE '2024-06-01', 1) AS "2024-06-01_1",
           (DATE '2024-06-01', 2) AS "2024-06-01_2",
           (DATE '2024-07-01', 1) AS "2024-07-01_1"
         )
       )

Outputs:



NAME
2024-01-01_1
2024-06-01_1
2024-06-01_2
2024-07-01_1




Aidan
A6
null
null
null


Alice
null
A4
null
A5


Roger
null
A1
A2
A3



fiddle

If you felt like using powerquery
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Award", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name", "Date"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Award", "Index"}, {"Award", "Index"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded data",0,null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Award", "Index"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "NewDate",  each if [Index]=null then Text.From([Date]) else Text.From([Date])&"-"&Text.From([Index])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[NewDate]), "NewDate", "Award")
in  #"Pivoted Column"

which is a bit complicated based on duplicated dates

or alternately
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Award", type text}}),
#"Group"= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name","Date"}, {{"Concat", each Text.Combine([Award],","), type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Group, {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Group, {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US")[Date]), "Date", "Concat")
in  #"Pivoted Column"



You can manipulate the source before pivoting, so (using SQL Server) i did this
with cteBase as
(
    select 
    t.name,t.date,
    STRING_AGG(t.award,',')  as awards
    from #t as t
    group by t.name,t.date
)
select 
*
from
cteBase as base
pivot
(
    max(awards) for [date] in ([2024-01-01],[2024-06-01],[2024-07-01])
) as pvt
order by name

Which gives

Not sure on the best solution idea, but there will be ways to make it possible :)

If you have a dynamic list of dates, you will not be able to use PIVOT without using custom PL/SQL functions to dynamic pivoting (you will find several like the "Anton's pivoting" on amis.nl).
What you can achieve in SQL is to generate a result with the (row, col) values where the data should go in the spreadsheet and then generate the spreadsheet on client side:
(to be tested on large data sets)
with data(Name, Dat, Award) as (
    select 'Roger', date '2024-06-01', 'A1' union all
    select 'Roger', date '2024-06-01', 'A2' union all
    select 'Roger', date '2024-07-01', 'A3' union all
    select 'Alice', date '2024-06-01', 'A4' union all
    select 'Alice', date '2024-07-01', 'A5' union all
    select 'Aidan', date '2024-01-01', 'A6'
),
rownames(rn, name) as (
    select dense_rank() over(order by name), name from 
    (select distinct name from data)
),
colnames(dat, cn) as (
    select dat, row_number() over(order by dat, level) 
    from (
        select dat, max(c) as n from (
            select dat, name, count(*) as c from data
            group by dat, name
        )
        group by dat
    )
    connect by level <= n and prior dat = dat and prior sys_guid() is not null
),
colstats(dat, name, n) as (
    select dat, name, count(*) from data
    group by dat, name
),
coldelta(name, award, delta) as (
    select
        name, award, row_number() over(partition by d.name, d.dat order by d.award) as delta
    from 
        (select distinct name, dat, award from data) d
),
rdata(rn, cn, Name, Dat, Award, rw, delta) as (
    select rn, cn, Name, Dat, Award, rw, delta
    from (
        select 
            rn,
            cn,
            d.name, d.dat, d.award,
            row_number() over(partition by d.name, d.dat, d.award order by cn) as rw, 
            cd.delta
        from data d
        join rownames r on r.name = d.name
        join colnames c on c.dat = d.dat 
        join colstats cs on cs.dat = c.dat and cs.name = d.name
        join coldelta cd on cd.name = r.name and cd.award = d.award 
    )
    where rw = delta
)
select rn, cn, name, dat, award 
from rdata 
order by rn, cn, award
;




rn
cn
name
dat
award




1
1
Aidan
01/01/24
A6


2
2
Alice
01/06/24
A4


2
4
Alice
01/07/24
A5


3
2
Roger
01/06/24
A1


3
3
Roger
01/06/24
A2


3
4
Roger
01/07/24
A3




To go further in previous answer, if you add the following WITH clause you will able to generate JSON array of each row (from there it's also easy to get a CSV):
,result as (
    select rn, cn, name, dat, award, rw,
        lag(cn,1) over(partition by rn order by cn) as prev_cn,
        lead(cn,1) over(partition by rn order by cn) as next_cn,
        max(cn) over() as max_cn
    from rdata 
)
select * from (
    select 0 as rn, '[ "NAME",' || listagg(distinct '"' || to_char(dat,'dd-mm-yyyy') ||
        case when rw > 1 then '/' || (rw-1) end || '"' ,',') within group(order by cn)
        || ' ]'
         as columns
    from (select dat,cn, rw from result)
    
    union all
    
    select rn, '[ "' || name || '",'
        || listagg( 
            case when prev_cn is null 
                then rpad(' ', (cn-1)*3+1, '"",') || '"' || award || '"'
                else rpad(' ', (cn-prev_cn-1)*3+1, '"",') || case when cn > 1 then '"' else '"' end || award || '"'
            end
            ||
            case when next_cn is null
                then rpad(' ', (max_cn-cn)*3+1, ',""')
            end
                -- || rpad(' ', (nvl(next_cn, max_cn)-cn)*4+1, ',">"')
            , ',') within group(order by cn)
        || ' ]'
    from result
    group by rn, name
)
order by rn
;


0   [ "NAME","01-01-2024","01-06-2024","01-06-2024/1","01-07-2024" ]
1   [ "Aidan", "A6" ,"","","" ]
2   [ "Alice", "","A4", "","A5"  ]
3   [ "Roger", "","A1", "A2", "A3"  ]

